# How to even out margins around a border?

Tags: formatting, margins

Any ideas as to why the document seems to shift up and to the right on the page? I've tried using {anysize} and {geometry} to adjust the borders but I've had some issues. With {geometry} the margin values aren't recognized unless I remove [margin] from documentclass. And doing so causes the title sections to appear above the text instead of to the side. And anysize works, but the right margin just goes to zero and the text falls off the page.

I'm looking to center the text and the border of the page while maintaining the section titles to the left. This is just a skeleton of my resume by the way. I hope that's ok.

```
% LaTeX file for resume 
% This file uses the resume document class (res.cls)

\documentclass[margin]{res}  % the margin option causes section titles to appear to the left of body text 
%\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin
\usepackage{enumitem} 
%\usepackage{Verdana} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\usepackage{fancybox}
%\usepackage{anysize}
%\marginsize{1in}{1in}{1in}{1in}

\begin{document} 

\thisfancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(7,9.5)}


\name{NAME}
\address{First@last.com\\ (111) 111-1111}


\begin{resume} 

\small{\section{Education} 
  text  
\vspace{-.5em}
\section{Related Coursework}    
  text   
\section{Experience}

 {\bf text,} text  \hfill   {\bf date} 
             \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-5pt]
             \item text
             \item text             
             \item text

            \end{itemize}

{\bf text,} text \hfill {\bf date}                
             \begin{itemize} [noitemsep,topsep=-5pt]
             \item text                                 
             \item text                 
             \item text

             \end{itemize}      
\vspace{-1em}        
    \section{Employment}
     \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
                \item {\bf text,} text \hfill   {\bf date} \newline                                                                              
                    \indent {text} 
                 \item {\bf text,}  text \hfill   {\bf date} \newline                                        
                    \indent {text} \newline
                    \indent {text}
                 \item {\bf text,}  text  \hfill   {\bf date} \newline                                          
                    \indent {text}\newline
                    \indent {text}                  
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-1em}        
\section{Honors \\ Affiliations}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text &text\\  
text &text\\ 
text &text\\
text &text
\end{tabular}

\section{Skills}   
    text



\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The extra margin is coming from the pdf driver.  Add 
\pdfpagewidth=8.5in
\pdfpageheight=11in in the preamble.

Comment: Wow. Thank you SO SO much. That was perfect. Concise and simple. I was tweaking so many things. THANKS!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician - There is probably a duplicate question somewhere.  It turns out that the geometry package takes care of this detail, so it doesn't come up very often.

Answer (score 1):

The extra margin is due to  the pdf driver.
Add `\pdfpagewidth=8.5in \pdfpageheight=11in` in the preamble.